# Enforce function parameter length to be same as array / tuple length

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

I'm writing a function that takes two parameters, A and B.
A is an array of strings with length L.
B is a function that takes L numbers as parameters and returns a number.

```
const acceptSameLength = (stringArray: string[], fnc: (...inputNums: number[]) => number) => ({
    names: stringArray,
    calcFunc: fnc
})
```

I'd like to enforce L being consistent between the two.

```
acceptSameLength(['foo'], (a: number) => 123) // Should work fine
acceptSameLength(['foo'], (a: number, b: number) => 123) // Should error
acceptSameLength(['foo', 'bar'], (a: number) => 123) // Should error
```

Because the function takes numbers as the parameters, but the array is of strings, I can't just use

```
T extends string[], U extends T
```

which does work for instances where the types are consistent, and my attempts of using a union type with `Exclude` also failed, but I didn't pursue that line of reasoning for a particularly long time.

The following fails as the spread operator can't be used. However, the logic for deriving the length of the tuple works fine.

```
const myAttempt = <
    T extends (readonly [] | readonly unknown[]) & (number extends T["length"] ? readonly [] : unknown),
>(
    categories: T,
    fnc: (...args: { [K in keyof T]: number }) => number,
) => {
    return {
        names: categories,
        calcFunc: fnc,
    };
};
```

The function is invoked with a known, hard-coded set of parameters, so using tuples is okay, but in the near future there will be instances where this is used with lengths of 20-30 and I'd like to avoid hardcoding each different overload (plus, it makes the code a lot cleaner!).

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/wXlVDw) work for you? If yes, I'll write an answer explaining; If not, what am I missing?

Comment: @wonderflame I think so! Thank you so much, would be very grateful for an answer to upvote, and will study the playground carefully.

Comment: sure, will do as soon as I get a chance

Comment: Hi, apologies, I've just tried to use it, and I'm [getting an error](https://tsplay.dev/WGBxVm) (hopefully quite easy). When I annotate the function with `: number` on the example that should work, it errors, expecting an array of numbers as the parameter, and the spread operator induces a recursive error. I'm currently having a look, but if you notice anything quickly, please let me know!

Comment: can you include the example?

Comment: It's linked under getting an error: https://tsplay.dev/WGBxVm

Comment: @wonderflame: I've managed to get it failing for being too long, but not too short: https://tsplay.dev/WYlO3m

Comment: I think @wonderflame has this covered, but you really don't want it to fail for being "too short"; see [the relevant FAQ entry](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#why-are-functions-with-fewer-parameters-assignable-to-functions-that-take-more-parameters).  Unless you want the callback in `[1, 2, 3].map(x => x+1)` to fail for its param list being "too short", of course.

Comment: @jcalz - great to see you again! My saviour many times in the past!
In this situation, I'm creating a library, and it's almost 100% likely that in the cases where it is "too short", the developer has missed an argument and I would like the compiler to flag it.
This is the solution I have now, which correctly errors: https://tsplay.dev/Wv1Bkm

Comment: @RichardCoates I suggest you writing your approach as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution to this came via realising that there was an inverse way of looking at the problem: instead of trying to restrict the parameters of the function by referencing the array, we could instead restrict the array, by referencing the parameters of the function!

```
function myAttempt<T extends number[]>(
    categories?: string[] & { [K in keyof T]: string },
    calcFunc?: (...args: T) => number,
) {
    return {
        category: category,
        categories: categories,
        calcFunc: calcFunc as (...args: number[]) => number,
    };
}
```

As you can see [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=13&ssc=78&pln=1&pc=1#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAQwhApgBygZWQW3QBl0wBzKACwB4AVRdADylIBMBnRMEfAI3QBOAbQC6APgAUAKESzEEZCzJwBMdOwD8ALkTsoq8qMQAyRAG9EQgNKIYSANboAnnGCJaInXoNlEAXwAaGTkFABsIADFwCG1ECQA6ROQBMnYdWgBKRABeMS4efgEgrLNg2QF0KBABJFK5evlFdGVVdR0FJRU1diCGkORwqMh2gcjolE4EpJS0-L5BUSzcucLeuT8Abik-KSlUDGw8QhJyKgkhACJKdFDQuAuRALjkHW55gSW85AyNxAB6P6IHCUOAgUKsRAAdxU9kQwDs6D2aCwuAIxFIFEo5yuNzuFyeF2hAnBDyeEheK0EnxQP3+gOBoPBDAEAhUSIOqOOGLOl2ut3uj2erwKgievGF72pyEQAGpELxaQCgSCwRDBKyBEA), this fulfils what I was looking for.